# How to modularize an ejs application

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have a server side rendering application that runs on nodejs and renders different ejs views based on the client routing.
I'm trying to slim down the code and create some reusable modules that I can call in my vies (the client side)
How do I go about it?
Basically I want to be able to have either js or ejs files with functions that I can export and then Import within the views to be used in specific parts of the code.

I've tried creating a js file (exportingFile.js) with a function in it.
I'm exporting that function by just doing

```
export function something(){
...
}
```

Then on my views I try importing the function doing the following:

```
<script type="module">
import { something} from "./exportingFile.js";
</script>
```

When doing that I get the following error:
**Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.**

Any thoughts on how I could accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Thanks!

Comment: One option would be to use the [import()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import) promise-based function

Comment: could you expand on that please!?

Comment: Sorry, actually I did some checking and the `import()` function has the same strict mime type checking. If you have control over your web server, you might need to check its configuration to be sure it's returning the correct `content-type: application/javascript` for your JS files.